# Finding Optimal Starting Point In Weighted Graph

Tags: algorithm, graph

[image: Graph For The Problem]

For the following graph, I need to find the optimal location that minimizes the distance to the farthest location. I was thinking that a possible solution would be to run Dijkstra's algorithm for each vertex. I'm not sure if this is an acceptable solution and if it is how to determine the running time?

Is my logic of using Dijkstra's algorithm on every vertex correct? If so, what would the running time on that be?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is the graph radius. Check [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/240556/radius-diameter-and-center-of-graph) out graph for instance.